# Can I change to a cheaper domain registrar when renewing a domain?

Tags: domains, domain-registrar

I set up a website on Cirrus Hosting, but it always remained "under construction" because my reach exceeded my grasp and limited time. Now they have asked me to send me new credit card information so that they can renew my expiring domain.

I want to retain the domain in case I ever use it (bit of a long shot, I will admit) but would like to ideally remove it from a third party and hold it at the cheapest place where I can get renewals and not pay for hosting.

Comment: You can find another domain registrar and just transfer it there if it's not already expired. Search "domain transfer prices" for the extension of your domain (e.g., `.com`), and also view their renewal rates which you'll pay the following years. After you select a domain registrar, then follow their transfer steps. You'll need to be able to log into your current registrar (e.g., Cirrus Hosting), unlock the domain, and then get a transfer code to provide to the new registrar, which should be detailed in their support documents.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer.  I will now parse it carefully so that I follow all the requisite steps.

Comment: Before anything make sure that you are properly listed as owner of the domain. Do also note that webhoster, DNS provider and domain name registrar are different things even if they can be done by the same company. Sometimes, it may help by using different companies in different roles. That avoids problems like DNS service being cut off immediately once the domain is transfered out (messing then resolution, because of DNS caches that will retain old nameservers configuration for some time)

Comment: You should advise us of the TLD/CCTLD of the domain (eg .com / .co.uk whatever).  In general, you can shift your domain to another cheaper registrar.  While cheaper is not always better, there are discount providers that are "good enough".

Answer (score 5):

Find the cheapest renewal price you can<sup>1</sup> and then institute a registration transfer<sup>2</sup>. It differs a bit between extensions e.g. .com is different to .co.uk which is different to .com.au.

Note the you need to *pull* the domain to the new registrar, not *push* it from the old one. So the first thing to do is create your account at the new registrar. Then get the EPP code (domain password) from the old registrar and ensure privacy is disabled and the domain is unlocked - again, not all domain extensions need this.

At the new registrar, institute a *transfer in* order. This is the point you will need the EPP code.

Some registrars will send an approval email which needs to be clicked for the process to proceed. Once that is done (or if it isn't needed) the transfer usually takes a few days.

The nameservers will remain unchanged.

---

<sup>1</sup> Cheapest is not necessarily best, it depends on a few things.

<sup>2</sup> Do this *at least* a week before it expires.

Comment: "The nameservers will remain unchanged." In most cases yes (the EPP gTLD model) but not all (ex: fr, be, eu, etc.). "^do this at least a week before it expires" I recommend at least one month before expiration, if not more. Do note that some registrars will renew in advance, especially if they have your credit card in advance. Even then you can still transfer after renew, but beware of side effects (the renewal can be reversed in certain cases, so you pay for 2 years but get only one)

Comment: Thanks @PatrickMevzek, I have never seen that nameserver thing happen as I don't generally deal with those domain extensions.  The CC wasn't considered as an issue as the OP says they want his card details.

Comment: If the domain is not in active  use, the nameservers make no difference.